# Finding short vectors for a lattice with a real-valued bilinear form in SageMath

Tags: sage, mathematical-lattices

I have a 2 x 2 matrix with *real* entries in SageMath, which represents the values of a bilinear form on a basis for a lattice, and I would like to find short (even better, the shortest!) vectors in this lattice.

Unfortunately, Sage's `short_vectors()` method seems to only work for lattices equipped with bilinear forms into *the integers*.

Does anyone know a work-around to find short vectors in lattices with real-valued bilinear forms in Sage?